# RoR Associations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I am trying to make a RoR project and I am currently have issues with Model Association. This is probably caused by an error or misunderstanding but in the last 2 days I have not been able to find this error or misunderstanding.

I want the associations to work like this:

```
User  
    => gapiToken  
    => userSession
```

So that technically I could just call `User.find(foo).gapiToken`.

Currently I have it setup so

```
User  
    has_many :userSessions  
    has_one :gapiToken  

UserSession  
    belongs_to :user  

GapiToken  
    belongs_to :user
```

However for some reason this does not seam to be working.
For example, this piece of code:

```
@user = User.create(gid: foo, permissions: bar)
@gapiToken = @user.gapiToken.create(access_token: foo, token_type: bar, expires_on: bazz, refresh_token: bop)
#^ Error ^ "undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass"
```

Am I going about this wrong in the usage or in the setup, or both?

**[Complete code](http://pastebin.com/UZn5PBBV)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be sure to follow conventions. Use under_scores, not camelCase:

```
User  
    has_many :user_sessions
    has_one :gapi_token
```

Second, the method `@model_instance.association.create` is for `one-to-many` associations, not `one-to-one` associations. It should be:

`@user.create_gapi_token(...)`

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) for more information about the associations API.

---

#### A note on [YOUR CODE](http://pastebin.com/UZn5PBBV)

Don't forget indexes.

A basic rule of thumb: index foreign keys, and index both keys on a join table. Example:

```
create_table :user_sessions do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user # will result in t.integer :user_id
end

add_index :user_sessions, :user_id

create_table :gapi_tokens, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user
end

add_index :gapi_tokens, :user_id
```

Example of an index on a join table (note `id: false` and `unique: true`):

```
create_table :users_favourites, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.belongs_to :favourite
end

add_index :users_favourites, [:user_id, :favourite_id], unique: true
```

Read [about migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html), then read and re-read the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

It's important you understand the conventions so you don't shoot yourself in the foot later down the road.

Comment: Will accept when I get back from dinner, won't let me now, thanks

Comment: @NoahHuppert could you explain with `t.string :gid` is for in your `users` table?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guess I got  little bit mixed up between when to use camel and underscore. For the GapiToken could you make the users id the apiToken's primary key?

Comment: gid is the Google User ID.

Comment: @NoahHuppert I think it's correct to have `gid` separate from the user's `id`, then.